# Effiecient way to find the object whose key value is close to a given value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using ES6. Assuming I have a sorted array like below. Not using lodash or any other library except jquery.

```
    sortedArray = [
    {a: "a", b: 2, c: "something1"},
    {a: "a1", b: 3, c: "something2"},
    {a: "a2", b: 4, c: "something3"},
    {a: "a3", b: 5, c: "something4"},
    {a: "a4", b: 6, c: "something5"},
    {a: "a5", b: 7, c: "something6"}
]
```

Is there an efficient way to find out the object whose key b value is closest to the provided a value.

If I provide a value 3.9, it should return `{a: "a2", b: 4, c: "something3"}`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Or do a binary search.

Comment: But if it is not sorted on `b` already, a single pass linear search should be the most efficient.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari If he is going to do a linear scan then what's the point of sorting?

Comment: Why do you explicitely ask for an efficient way? Do you have actual performance issues, or is this just some premature optimization? About what amount of work are we talking here? How many items has `sortedArray` and how often do you perform such a search per second?

Comment: How often will the find take place?

Comment: Oh, and what if two items are equally far away? For example if you search for `3.5`. Wich one should be returned?

Comment: What is your array sorted by?  Is it sorted by the values of the `.b` key?  Or by something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `reduce` (so should be slow on big arrays...):

```
sortedArray = [
    {a: "a", b: 2, c: "something1"},
    {a: "a1", b: 3, c: "something2"},
    {a: "a2", b: 4, c: "something3"},
    {a: "a3", b: 5, c: "something4"},
    {a: "a4", b: 6, c: "something5"},
    {a: "a5", b: 7, c: "something6"}
]
const search = 3.9
sortedArray.reduce((p,v)=> Math.abs(p.b-search) < Math.abs(v.b-search) ? p : v)
// {a: "a2", b: 4, c: "something3"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not the computationally most efficient, but the shortest I can think of:

```
let target = 3.9;
sortedArray.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(a.b - target) > Math.abs(b.b - target))[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you explicitly asked for the efficient way to find the closest element in an array of sorted objects, I suggest employing a binary search strategy:

Start with the whole interval of indices from `0` up to `array.length - 1` and look at the middle element:

- Is it smaller? Continue searching in the higher interval.
- Is it bigger? Continue searching in the lower interval.

This search strategy finds the closest element in a logarithmic number of steps, i.e. in O(log n). Searching via `reduce` completes in O(n) and sorting by difference and picking the top element completes in O(n log n).

The resulting code is certainly not elegant, but rather efficient:

```js
// Find object whose b is closest to value:
function findClosest(objects, value) {
  let lowest = 0;
  let highest = objects.length - 1;
  let difference = Infinity;
  let closest;
  
  while (lowest <= highest) {
    let index = highest + lowest >> 1;
    let current = objects[index];
    
    if (Math.abs(current.b - value) < difference) {
      closest = current;
      difference = Math.abs(closest.b - value);
    }
    if (current.b > value) {
      highest = index - 1;
    } else if (current.b < value) {
      lowest = index + 1;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return closest;
}

// Example:
let sortedArray = [
  {a: "a" , b: 2, c: "something1"},
  {a: "a1", b: 3, c: "something2"},
  {a: "a2", b: 4, c: "something3"},
  {a: "a3", b: 5, c: "something4"},
  {a: "a4", b: 6, c: "something5"},
  {a: "a5", b: 7, c: "something6"}
];

console.log(findClosest(sortedArray, 3.9));
```